# Spotify API sometimes works, sometimes returns 400: Bad Request error

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, spotify

Alright, I'm doing some tests with the spotify-api. After I got the authentication-token (PKCE) to send a request for the token I need to see data, I sometimes get an error and sometimes not. For Example: On Edge it only works in incognito, on firefox only in localhost and never on chrome. My code snipped that makes the request to spotify is this:

```
    // Current Playback
    let data = {
        client_id: "6b18daee53bd4b1fba17ad64f95a35f0",
        grant_type: "authorization_code",
        code: code,
        redirect_uri: uri,
        code_verifier: verifier
    }
    let Url = "https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token"
    $.ajax({
        url: Url,
        type: "POST",
        data: data,
        success: function(result){
            console.log(result)
            window.location.href = "./stats.html?token=" + result.access_token;
        },
        error: function(error){
            console.log(`Error ${error}`)
            document.location.href = "./authorize.html?error=" + error;
        }
    })
}
```

Why does it work only sometimes, and not every time?